# How to pass variable of inbuilt date class to another class

Tags: android, date, datetime, calendar

I am implementing an "android app". I want to pass a value of inbuilt date class to another class.

I have first class is "SelectActivity.java" and second class is "Insert.java". SelectActivity.java class contain this Date class variable
For example:

```
 Date cdate = new Date();
 java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTime(cdate);
 c.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, 2); 
 cdate = c.getTime();
```

I want to pass the value of cdate to other class that is Insert.java.
How to pass this vlaue. Please help me. How to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any data via `Intent`. Simply use :

Pass :

```
intent.putExtra("date", date.getTime());
```

Retrieve :

```
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(i.getLongExtra("date", -1));
```

Comment: `Intent i = getIntent();` `d.setTime(i.getLongExtra("date", -1));` try this

Comment: Did you add all import statements ?

Comment: Is your class a Fragment?

Comment: Nope 1st class is extends by activity and second class is extends by AsyncTask<>

Comment: of both class? or only one class

Comment: Please go through this link http://codeshare.io/DvvJV in myCustomHandler class you will find intent method

Comment: Where did you pass the date through intent? I couldn't find that

Comment: I am passing intent into Insert.java class @Jas

Answer (score 0):

From the current Insert.java activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("date", dateObj.getTime());
startActivity(intent);
```

From next SelectActivity.java activity:

```
Date dateObj = new Date(getIntent().getExtras().getLongExtra("date", -1));
```

Comment: I followed your idea but in selecavtivity.java class getIntent() show cannot resolve method getIntent() @sasikumar

Comment: Use getActivity() in Fragment  like getActivity().getIntent()

Answer (score 0):

In SelectActivity add

```
intent.putExtra("date",Date);
```

Receive it in inseractivity using

```
Date date = new Date(extras.getString("date"));
```